# How to document Vue Single-File Components that use the Composition API?

Tags: vuejs3, jetbrains-ide, jsdoc, vue-composition-api, vue-sfc

Without relying on a third party package, what is the "correct" way to document my **Vue 3 Single-File Components** using the **Composition API** in a way that allows an IDE (in my case JetBrains' IntelliJ IDEA) to show e.g. documentation pop-ups, when I hover over the name of the component in a file that depends on it?

The challenge is that there is no explicit exports in a SFC that uses the Composition API.

I've tried adding a jsdoc comment at the top of the setup script (above its imports), but that did not work.

Comment: This is rather a random comment (since I'm not into Vue/JS at all) .. but I'm wondering if **Web Types** be of any good here. 1) https://github.com/JetBrains/web-types 2) https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/websymbols-web-types.html . Quite possibly not (let me know anyway)